# Uncaught TypeError: on my preloader. How to make it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, preloader

I have always used this code to preload the pages, now I was testing it with wordpress, but I generate the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function**

The file is attached to an external file. As you can see from the demo. What am I doing wrong? Thank you :)

[Used previosly](http://promo.contat.eu/)

[LIVE LINK](http://montesilvano.contat.eu/)

```
$(window).load(function() { 
 $(".loader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `jQuery.noConflict()` from your modified copy of jQuery, so that unbinds the `$` symbol.

If you're not using a conflicting library, there's no need to do that.  If you remove that line, things will work. Alternatively you could wrap your preload code like this:

```
;(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() { 
    $(".loader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); 
  });
})(jQuery);
```